# Machine override per all machines except one

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have the following content in bbappend file:

```
do_install_prepend () {
# do sth
}
```

It is easily possible to override per single machine e.g.:

```
do_install_prepend_qmeux86-64
```

How to make an override for all machines except one? Task do_install cannot be wiped out, because it contains the default scripts.

Comment: Why don't you turn it around? Make the desired install_prepend global, and override it for the exceptional case.

Comment: How can you override content of _prepend?

Comment: Uhhh, fair enough, maybe I typed without fully comprehending your question :D 2nd thought: you could inspect the `MACHINE` variable inside  do_install_prepend: `if [ "${MACHINE}" != "TERMINATOR" ]; then ...`

Comment: yeah, that's what I did, however moving flow control from bitbake switches inside funcions is not the cleanest solution if project is big and plenty of machines in use

Comment: 3rd thought: create a separate task for this step, and stick it between compile and install: `addtask special_install after compile before install`. You can override this `special_install` for your machine, like other tasks.